# Can I set my own order for folders in a Visual Studio 2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio, directory, visual-studio-2008

If I create new folder in a Visual Studio project, Visual Studio will automatically reorder all the project folders alphabetically. I want to order them as I want.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The only way I've found to achieve something close to that outcome is to prefix the folder with a number to create the ordering. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i use prefix folders with"_" to do that